# Angular Uploading a File with Copy Paste

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have an `Upload` button that enables the user to search files and upload them. I also defined a `textarea` and I want the user to be able to paste the file that he copied and upload it that way (like you would do in an e-mail or whatsapp etc.). Right now, when I try to paste the file that I've copied, nothing happens and the file doesn't paste. My code is below. What should I do to upload files by paste?

HTML:

```
<div>
        <button mat-stroked-button class="primary-fg" (click)="onFileUploadClick($event)">
            <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
            Upload
        </button>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Paste</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput
                      cdkTextareaAutosize
                      #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                      cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
                      cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"
                      id="pasteArea"></textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
           <script>
            window.addEventListener("paste", e => {
                if (e.clipboardData.files.length > 0) {
                    const fileInput = document.querySelector("#fileInput");
                    fileInput.files = e.clipboardData.files;
                }
            });
        </script>

    </div>
        <input hidden type="file" id="fileInput" #fileInput multiple />
```

TS:

```
onFileUploadClick(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput') as HTMLInputElement;
        fileInput.value = '';
        fileInput.onchange = () => {
            let tempFiles: IAttachment[] = [];
            for (let index = 0; index < fileInput.files.length; index++) {
                const file = fileInput.files[index];
                const fileSize = file.size / 1024 / 1024; // in MB
                if (fileSize <= 5) {
                    tempFiles.push({ FileInfo: file });
                }
                else {
                    this._dialog.open(FuseSimpleDialogComponent, {
                        width: "400px",
                        data: {
                            title: "Uyarı",
                            message: "Dosya boyutu 5MB'den büyük olduğundan seçilemez. Dosya Adı: " + file.name
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            tempFiles.forEach(f => this.uploadFile(f));
        };
        fileInput.click();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    private uploadFile(file: IAttachment) {

        if (file.FileData) return; //file already uploaded

        let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        let $that = this;
        let data: any;

        fileReader.onerror = function (): void {
            //show error message
        };

        fileReader.onloadend = function (): void {

            if (FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString) {
                data = btoa(fileReader.result as string);
            }
            else { //support for IE
                data = ($that as any).arrayBufferToBase64(fileReader.result);
            }

            file.Name = file.FileInfo.name;
            file.FileData = data;
            file.CreateDate = new Date();
            file.CreateUser = $that.user;

            let allFiles = $that.Attachments ? $that.Attachments.slice(0) : [];
            allFiles.unshift(file);
            $that.Attachments = allFiles;
            $that.AttachmentsChange.emit(allFiles);
        };

        if (FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString) {
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file.FileInfo);
        }
        else { //support for IE
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.FileInfo);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Careful with you approach, simply pasting a file into a `textarea` will do nothing as a text area is made to receive... text.

You need to have an `input file` somewhere on your component and an event listener on `window` for the `paste` event.

Then take the paste event and try to see if it includes a file, if yes, start the uploading process, if not, paste the text in the `textarea`.

This is how I would approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same thing using the HostListener and it is working for me. For your reference, I'm going to attach my TS, HTML, and SCSS files.

HTML:

```
<div class="file-drop-area" *ngIf="!multiple">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Choose file</button>
  <span>{{ file ? file.name : " or drag and drop file here" }}</span>
  <input class="file-input" type="file" />
</div>

<div class="file-drop-area" *ngIf="multiple">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Choose files</button>
  <span *ngIf="!fileList">{{ " or drag and drop files here" }}</span>
  <input class="file-input" type="file" multiple />
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 mt-2" *ngIf="multiple">
  <span *ngFor="let file of arrFileList; let index = index"
    >{{ file.name }}
    <app-feather-icons
      [icon]="'trash-2'"
      [class]="'tbl-fav-delete'"
      (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)"
    >
    </app-feather-icons>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</div>
```

TS:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-types */
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: FileUploadComponent,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.scss'],
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input()
  multiple = false;

  onChange!: Function;
  public file: File | null = null;
  public fileList: FileList | null = null;
  public arrFileList = [];

  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.files']) emitFiles(event: FileList) {
    if (event && event.length === 1 && !this.multiple) {
      const file = event && event.item(0);
      this.onChange(file);
      this.file = file;
    } else if (event && event.length > 0 && this.multiple) {
      console.log(event);
      const fileList = event;
      this.fileList = fileList;
      this.arrFileList = Array.from(fileList);
      this.onChange(this.arrFileList);
      this.writeValue(null);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:paste', ['$event']) onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    if (event && event.clipboardData.files.length > 0) {
      if (event.clipboardData.files.length === 1 && !this.multiple) {
        const file = event.clipboardData.files[0];
        this.onChange(file);
        this.file = file;
      } else if (this.multiple) {
        console.log(event);
        const fileList = event.clipboardData.files;
        this.fileList = fileList;
        this.arrFileList = Array.from(fileList);
        this.onChange(this.arrFileList);
        this.writeValue(null);
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {}

  removeSelectedFile(index) {
    // Delete the item from fileNames list
    this.arrFileList.splice(index, 1);
    this.onChange(this.arrFileList);
  }

  writeValue(value: null) {
    // clear file input
    this.host.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.file = null;
    this.fileList = null;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: Function) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: Function) {
    // add code here
  }
}
```

SCSS:

```
.file-drop-area {
  border: 1px dashed #7c7db3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 26px 20px 30px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.file-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
.file-msg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #5b5bff;
}
```